# SQL - Multiple Inner Join, most recent

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am wondering why the below SQL query does not work properly. I am attempting to return the fields from table 1 and table 2 based on the most recent date AND only those elements in those tables that have the name Steve from a third table.

This query, meanwhile, does not actually limit the results to those with the name of Steve. If I remove the second Inner Join and focus on fields only in Table 1 to limit the universe, it works fine.

Appreciate your help on this. I am using Microsft SQL Server Management Studio.

```
   Select * 
    From [db].table1
    INNER JOIN [db].table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
    INNER JOIN [db].table3 ON table1.id=table3.id

    WHERE (table1.AsOfDate=(SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) from [db].table1)) 
    and table3.Name = 'Steve'
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. odd column names like `"xy 123 %"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'Steven'`.

Comment: All ids are same for each table, no usage of foreign key?

Comment: You really need to post the schema, or at least enough of it for us to be able to answer.  As it stands, this is an indeterminate problem.

Comment: Add your used DBMS

Comment: Which dbms????  The dbms you are using determine what query you are getting.  So tag it properly!!!

Comment: Added my DBMS - apologies.

Comment: All of these tables are in one database

Comment: Some sample data and expected expect would help.

Comment: I just created some temp tables and wrote the same query and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The ID's may not be referring to the same ID across all three tables. Your joins assumes that is the case though. I mirrored your query with sample temp tables and your query works.

```
--SAMPLE TABLES
IF object_id('tempdb..#table1') is not null drop table #table1
if object_id('tempdb..#table2') is not null drop table #table2
if object_id('tempdb..#table3') is not null drop table #table3

CREATE TABLE #table1 (id INT, my_date date) 
INSERT INTO #table1 (id, my_date) VALUES
(1, '1/1/2018'),
(2, '1/2/2018'),
(3, '1/1/2018')

CREATE TABLE #table2 (id INT, some_field VARCHAR(10)) 
INSERT INTO #table2 (id, some_field) VALUES
(1, 'abc'),
(2, 'xyz'),
(3, 'foo')

CREATE TABLE #table3 (id INT, name VARCHAR(10)) 
INSERT INTO #table3 (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'jon'),
(2, 'steve'),
(3, 'jane')


--QUERY
SELECT * 
FROM #table1 AS x
    INNER JOIN 
    #table2 AS y ON x.id=y.id
    INNER JOIN 
    #table3 AS z ON z.id=x.id
WHERE x.my_date=(SELECT MAX(my_date) from #table1)
    and z.name = 'Steve'
```

output

```
id  my_date    id   some_field  id  name
2   2018-01-02  2   xyz        2    steve
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is a window function in the `order by`:

```
Select top (1) with ties . . .  -- list the columns explicitly 
from [db].table1 t1 join
     [db].table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id join
     [db].table3 t3
     on t1.id = t3.id
where t3.Name = 'Steve'
order by rank() over (order by t1.AsOfDate);
```